# Download Files from the Web

Tags: google-chrome, browser, download

I have a Text file named Data.dat on my Server.

I would like to to Download this file using the Chrome browser, but when I click on the download Link it just displays it, instead of downloading it.

I know that I can download *.zip or *.exe files.

Is there any way to download it in it's original format ?

Answer (score 0):

when you see the file(or the link) in browser right click on the file and chose save as and save the file where you wants it to be saved.